# How do you retrieve a caller ID from from a digital line or a VOIP phone?

Tags: delphi, voip, telephony, telecommunication, pbx

On my work place, we have some (PBX)Business Communications Manager 450 Telephone System and some (PBX)BCM50 also. The BCM450 is hybrid, which mean it can use digital lines and at the same time VOIP phones.

Right now, for example a user can have a Nortel Avaya 1120E or a Nortel T7316 Norstar  in their desk.

I would like to know if there is a way in which way I can get the phone number of the caller, so I can use that number on a custom software for the company. In other words I want the phone number of the person calling me (maybe the extension if that is the case).

What I'm looking for, is that when a customer calls, the information associated with the telephone number can be seen on the screen programmatically (without input from system operator).

I can see there is someone talking about [TAPI API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but i believe this is only for analog lines? Maybe somebody can put me on the right path or maybe somebody can provide an example of how it is done using any programming language.

Comment: Nothing about your question is related to C#, C++, or Delphi. Your question would be about the API that is being used to work with the phone systems. Until you've determined that API, the language is irrelevant. What API are you using to communicate from software to the two different phone systems?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe someone can provide me an example, using a programming language - sorry any confusion.

Comment: TAPI will work just fine with non-analog phones, as long as they are compatible with TAPI to begin with.  When you connect to TAPI, you are talking to the PBX, not the phones directly.  The PBX will send TAPI events to you describing the calls it is managing.

Answer (score 0):

If the VOIP phones are SIP based then you'd sniff eth. ports of the phones. SIP messages contains caller Id and called Id.

You can google like "SIP sniffer" for source code example...

Comment: SIP phones communicate with the PBX. Unless you can sniff the PBX's network from an outside machine, you will have to configure the PBX to forward the SIP requests to your app.  That means connecting a TCP/UDP socket to the PBX itself.  I know, because my company does exactly this in our software.

Comment: If you sniff Phone1 then you can record all Phone1 calls. This is extension based solution.

Comment: This would be a fine comment to the question, but "google like "SIP sniffer"" isn't really a suitable answer.

Comment: @SimaWB: Recording phone calls is my company's primary business (we also do screen recording and voice/video analytics).  Our recording software works with dozens of PBXs involving analog, digital, and VoIP phones. We use various PBX/monitoring APIs to get the audio and call data.  In VoIP phones, some APIs allow us to request the phones forward a copy of their audio directly to us. In other cases, we use specialized hardware to sniff and parse the network traffic coming from a SPAN (replication) port on the PBX. Trust me, recording phones and getting/parsing call data is not trivial.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I know you. And I'm a fanatic of you especially Indy :)  We're co-worker. Because my company's single business is voice recording. I respect you...

Comment: @RemyLebeau: can you elaborate a little bit more, on the solution your company use.

Comment: @Edgardo: that would be too complicated to explain here, not to mention a violation of our intellectual property (we have been in the recording business a LONG time). I will say that on some systems, we do use TAPI for call data, usually with phone lines that are hard-wired into our recorder for audio, but for SIP phones on those systems we use SIP for RTP audio. That is just one combination.  We use dozens of APIs for recording all kinds of other PBXs, utilizing call recording APIs and call data APIs from vendors like AI-Logix, Synway, Avaya, Motorola, or even proprietary third-party APIs.